# Windowing Functions for MySQL 5.7 32-bit

Tags: mysql, window-functions, mysql-5.7

Anyone please advise how to use windowing functions in MYSQL 5.7 and 32-bit OS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There aren't any until version 8 what are you trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You have some issues with your question, but it's OK, a lot of people do this while they're learning how to use the site. First, this is the wrong type of question to ask for a few reasons. Mainly, it is apparent that you have put no effort into the question. Second, SO is a place to get answers for more concrete problems. For example, if you had tried to do something with MySQL Windowing, but got an error, you could post the error. Your question will probably be closed because of this, but go ahead and try again, showing more research. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Window functions are available in MySQL 8.0 and newer. Alternatively, you could try using MariaDB 10.2.

For older versions of MySQL they are not available.